# layering and outlining on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been working on a seemingly simple graphic.  I wish to create circles, with a line connecting the circles, and filling the circles in with some background.  I have almost got it, but this one piece is tripping me up.

I can define the canvas, create the circles, and line connecting them just fine:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = $(window).width();
canvas.height = $(window).height();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;

//Create two nodes
ctx.arc( 100, 100, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(200+25, 200)
ctx.arc( 200, 200, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);

//line connecting two nodes
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);

ctx.stroke();
```

This would look like this:

[image]

What I then do is fill the circles with an image (this is why I use `clip()`), but using a white color fill for the sake of example demonstrates the problem as well:

```
//simulate filling in nodes with image, in this case solid color
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fill();
```

[image]

Now I am almost there, but there are some jagged edges there that I have read is just a little "bug" in Chrome, and also I like that thick black outline on the circles. So, I want to go back over **just the 2 circles** and outline them.  It seems no matter what I do, the context always remembers that line connecting the two, and I end up with the connector line over the top of the image after calling `stroke()`:

```
//would like to just re-outline circles, not connecting line
ctx.stokeStyle = "black";
ctx.arc( 100, 100, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(200+25, 200)
ctx.arc( 200, 200, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to just outline the 2 circles again after filling in the white background (loading the image)?

I think about it like drawing in layers.  First I draw some lines, then I put the images in, then I draw again on top.  Not sure if the html canvas is meant to be used like that.  Thanks.

[JSFiddle Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0rL4mjLn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to begin a new path.

Whenever you start a new shape you must use `ctx.beginPath` or the context will redraw all the previous paths.

BTW the jaggy circles is because you are re-rendering them, this causes the edges to get jaggies.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,-50); // just moving everything up to be seen in snippet.

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FAFAFF";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;

//Create two nodes
/*   dont draw the two circle the first time as you are
     doubling the render causing the edges to get to sharp
     making them appear jaggy.
ctx.arc( 100, 100, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(200+25, 200)
ctx.arc( 200, 200, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
*/
//line connecting two nodes
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);

ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();  // start a new path and removes all the previous paths

//Create two nodes
ctx.arc( 100, 100, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(200+25, 200)
ctx.arc( 200, 200, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();  // start a new path and removes all the previous paths

//Create two nodes
ctx.arc( 100, 100, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(200+25, 200)
ctx.arc( 200, 200, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: That was it, very helpful thanks!  Just a question, what do you mean by "re-rendering".  is there a different way to render them that helps with the jagged edge problem?  Your solution here definitely works but my production code loads the images asynchronously, so doing things like this doesn't work so well for some reason.  Also in your code you aren't using `clip` which I need to use to make the images the right size.  But anyways.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind re-rendering, I mean that you are drawing the circle again over itself. AntiAliasing works by drawing pixels with alpha at the edges, when you draw a shape a second time the pixels at the edge become darker (or lighter depending on colour) making them appear jaggy. You can still use clip but it has the same rules, use beginPath befor you define the clip (use beginPath every time you define a unique path). For the images, just wait till you have loaded the images before you render.